# OpenERP - UnicodeWarning: Unicode unequal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode

Tags: python, unicode, odoo

```
openerp/server/openerp/osv/orm.py:833: UnicodeWarning: Unicode unequal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if cols[k][key] != vals[key]:
```

I see this warning in a log. I don't know when this started happening. And what does it mean? How could I pinpoint the cause of this?

Comment: please provide the complete log

Comment: Well I don't know what to provide here, because it does not show anything else. Just normal stuff that everything is loading when you start server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, there was some field labels that had non ascii symbols. When I changed to it ascii only symbols, then this warning disappeared.

For example let say it was something like this:

```
_columns = {
    'some_field': fields.char('Field label with non ascii ęą'),
}
```

When I changed to:

```
_columns = {
    'some_field': fields.char('Field label with ascii only'),
}
```

Warning disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Just add u prefix before the string with non-ASCII characters. 
EX:

```
_columns = {
'some_field': fields.char(u'Field label with non ascii ęą'),
```

}